# Display multiple images in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin with Rails 5. I have a model `Hotel` with an association `images` (has_many). Currently I use the default config of rails_admin, and under `Hotel show` page, the images of a hotel are displayed in this format:

```
Image #5381, Image #5382, Image #5383, Image #5384, Image #5385,...
```

How can I display these images as a gallery given that each image has a `thumbnail_url` attribute? I means which config I could put in this block to change the display:

```
show do
  field :images do
    # Display as a gallery
  end
end
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering a custom partial is probably the best approach here. Something like:

```
field :images do
  render do
    bindings[:view].render partial: 'image_preview', locals: {object: self}
  end
end
```

Then create the partial in `app/views/rails_admin/main/_image_preview.html.*`, and you're free to control what appears.